# iOS 8 UITableView Faded out Checkmarks when not selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uistoryboard

Is there anyway to give the Checkmarks an alpha or color for when the UITableViewCell is not selected? By default, iOS just doesn't have a checkmark for when a row is not selected. Changing the color of the checkmark is straightforward, but I'm not sure if iOS supports functionality for displaying a checkmark faded out when the UITableViewCell is not selected.

I'm not interested in solutions that require external images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `tintColor` on `UITableViewCell` to change the transparency.

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
cell.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
```

The selected cell has `tintColor` with alpha set to `1`.

```
if selected[indexPath.row] {
    cell.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
} else {
    cell.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
}
```

Comment: Amazing, so simple.